# How to pull data for past x weeks dynamically in redshift?

Tags: sql, datetime, amazon-redshift, where-clause, date-arithmetic

I have a below query which I run gives me the single count for previous week which is `Week 43`. Current week is 44 as of now.

```
select
count(distinct(clientid))
from data_holder
left join name
on name.client_id = data_holder.clientid
where POC NOT IN ('SGH', 'IKU')
and status IN ('NOTTAKEN')
and (from <= '43' AND to >= '44')
```

As of now the output I see is this which is for Week 43-

```
Count
-----
124
```

Now I am trying to make this query dynamic such that it can give me count for past 6 weeks something like below as an output:

```
Count   Week
------------
124     W43
125     W42
126     W41
127     W40
128     W39
129     W38
```

I am able to convert above query in dynamic way which gives me the count for previous week which is 43 and it works fine but I am not sure how can I change it so that it can give me data for all past 6 weeks in the above output format.

```
select
count(distinct(clientid))
from data_holder
left join name
on name.client_id = data_holder.clientid
where POC NOT IN ('SGH', 'IKU')
and status IN ('NOTTAKEN')
and (from <= DATE_PART(w, CURRENT_DATE) -1 AND to >= DATE_PART(w, CURRENT_DATE))
```

**Update**

I ran below query and I am not seeing any data coming from below query -

```
with data_holder as
    (
    with tree_post as
    (Select contractid as conid, max(goldennmber) as goldennmber
    from zeus.user_keys_post group by contractid)
    Select * from tree_post join zeus.user_keys_post b
    on tree_post.conid = b.contractid and tree_post.goldennmber = b.goldennmber
    ),
     
    name as 
    (
    SELECT abc, client_id, services from dim.crom c1 where c1.ver = (SELECT MAX(ver) from dim.crom c2 
    where c1.client_id = c2.client_id)
    )
     
    select from,
    count(distinct(clientid))
    from data_holder
    left join name
    on name.client_id = data_holder.clientid
    where POC NOT IN ('SGH', 'IKU')
    and status IN ('NOTTAKEN')
    and from <= date_part(w, current_date - interval '6 weeks') 
    and to   >= date_part(w, current_date)
    group by from
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
AND "from" <= DATE_PART(w, CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL '6 weeks') 
AND "to"   >= DATE_PART(w, CURRENT_DATE))
```

Then, if you want one row per `from`, you can use `group by`. So:

```
select ??.from, count(distinct ??.clientid) cnt
from data_holder dh
left join name n on on n.client_id = dh.clientid
where 
    ??.poc not in ('SGH', 'IKU') 
    and ??.status = 'NOTTAKEN'
    and ??.from <= date_part(w, current_date - interval '6 weeks') 
    and ??.to   >= date_part(w, current_date)
group by ??.from
```

Note that I modified the query to use table aliases. I would also recommend prefixing each column with the table it belongs to, so the query is unambiguous about the underlying data structure: I had no clue, so I used `??`, which you need to replace with either `dh` or `n`.

I am also quite suspicious about the `left join`. Is there a good reason why you don't actually want an `inner join` instead?

Comment: Will it give me the data in the above output format for each week? I wasn't sure we have INTERVAL command that we can use like that.

Comment: @AndyP. See my update. There is a bit of guess though, since your question lacks some important information. You might need to review and adapt.

Comment: Sure let me try to adapt and see how it works. Let me do some reading on `INTERVAL` function as well.

Comment: I ran your suggestion but it looks like data is not coming at all. I updated my question with the full query I have. Is there anything I am missing?